# How do I check if the value is already present in the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

Is there a easier way to check the value entered in the textbox with the field in the database if it is already present or not? Because I find this a little complex. Thanks in advance.

```
    public int method(string a)
    {
        string str;
        int chk = 1;
        con = new OracleConnection(constr);
        con.Open();
        try
        {
            com = new OracleCommand("select a from table where a='" + a + "'", con);
            OracleDataReader dr;
            dr = com.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.Read())
            {
                str = dr["A"].ToString();
                if (str == a)
                    chk = 0;
                else
                    chk = 1;
            }
            else
                chk = 1;
            return chk;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, don't concatenate. Use parameters. Since you are using oracle that is `:name` syntax, IIRC. Secondly, you can use `ExecuteScalar` to be simpler, i.e.

```
public bool RecordExists(string a)
{
    using(var con = new OracleConnection(constr))
    using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "select 1 from table where a=:a";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("a", a);
        con.Open();
        return cmd.ExecuteScalar() != null; // returns null if no rows
    }
}
```

But frankly, you can also use tools like "dapper" to make it easier:

```
public bool RecordExists(string a)
{
    using(var con = new OracleConnection(constr))
    {
        return con.Query("select 1 from table where a=:a", new {a}).Any();
    }
}
```

(and yes, I know I didn't even `Open()` the connection)

Comment: Which namespace should I add for that `Query` class...??

Comment: @Aneez that would be `using Dapper;`, but you need the "dapper" package - which is [available from NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/dapper), or you can just use `Install-Package Dapper` in the VS package manager console

Answer (score 1):

You can use Read to decide if you got exact match as the query you have already check if the given value is present in database table. [OracleDataReader.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledatareader.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will return `true` if you get atleast one row.

```
if (dr.Read())
   return 1;             
else     
    return 0;
```

> Read returns true if there are more rows; otherwise, false, [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledatareader.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You can change the return type of method to bool and simply return result of read;

```
return dr.Read()
```